# Get index of Object inside Array and use it in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In Javascript, is it possible to get the Index of the object (in an array of objects) and use it inside of the same object in a function?

For example:

```
const foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
    comments: getComments(this.index) // index of the object goes here
  },
  {
    id: 34,
    comments: getComments(this.index) // index of the object goes here
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    comments: getComments(this.index) // index of the object goes here
  }
]

const getComments = function(index) {
  return foo[index].id // return the ID of the actual object
}
```

Or is there a workaround for what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: At the time you're calling the function, the array doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: What is `this.index` supposed to be?

Comment: Why do you need the index instead of the object itself?

Comment: Also `getComments` won't exist when the array is defined. (I am confused)

Comment: If this worked, you would just be setting `comments` to the same thing as the `id` property. What's the point of that?

Comment: It's also fine if I get the object itself, doesn't necessarily have to be the object. I'd just like to get access to its values. However, I can see now that what you're all saying. The array/object doesn't even exist by the time I''m trying to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps. First create the array of objects, then fill in the `comments` property by calling the function on each element.

```js
const foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 34,
  },
  {
    id: 21,
  }
]

foo.forEach(el => el.comments = getComments(el));

function getComments(obj) {
  return obj.id;
}

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Really nice, it makes sense to run a function after the array has been created. How silly of me to not thinking of that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for learning purposes as probably the use you are thinking could be implemented in a better way. The closest that you can do is this:

```js
let foo = [
  {
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 34,
  },
  {
    id: 21,
  }
]

foo = foo.map(
  (elem, index) => ({...elem, comments: getComments(index)})
)

function getComments(index) {
  return foo[index].id // return the ID of the actual object
}

console.log(foo[2].comments)
```